# How to make clang detect a new library I downloaded?

Tags: c++, clang, header-files, sdl-2

I am trying to learn SDL2 and have downloaded it on my Mac using Homebrew.
I use Neovim and wanted clang to detect the new library. I kinda understood that I need to link the .dylib file and the "include" folder with the headers to the folder that clang uses to detect libraries, but how do I do that? They are linked in the same directory? I also need to link it so that I can compile the code, but apparently I can use a Makefile for that.

Comment: You just need to define the lib path using -L/path/to/lib and -I/path/to/include

Comment: Makefiles just run the same commands you could run from the terminal. Learn how to compile from the terminal first.